# Closed distribution of an iPad App for longer than one year

Tags: ios, enterprise

We are using enterprise builds.
The enterprise builds run out after an year.
Is the a way or a service which allows me to distribute with out this year limit?
TIA
romka

Comment: Do you have an MDM serving out the app or did you install locally via Configurator?

Answer (score 2):

No but you can just distribute another build after one year.
That way you certificate renews and people can still download the app.

This is no big deal as it just involves a new signing of the App Bundle. All people that have installed the App on their devices have no problems as they do not have to redownload the App. The new signing is just required for new downloaders.

And I think if you have a serious App you are distributing here, than this should be no barrier at all, cause one update per year should be absolute plausible (especially in mind that iOS and the iPhones/iPads receive an Update every year and a whole lot changes and might break in your app)

Answer (score 1):

In enterprise accounts the certificates expire after 3 years and the provisioning profile after one year. So after the year ends you have to resubmit your app with an updated provisioning profile.